# Binding local image using v-for - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

## What is the problem

I want to use link, which comes from v-for as src to my image. The problem is that when I pass it using require it says me the it's unable to find image at given location. It's especially confusing because this link works perfectly within the **img** tag.

## Code

```
<section class="DataContainer" v-for="property in state.properitesToShow" :key="property">
   <section>
     {{property.name}}
     <img src="../assets/icons/virus2.svg"> // this works
     <img :src="require(property.imgSrc)"> // this not
    </section>
</section>
```

### Mentioned list

```
const state = reactive({
      properitesToShow: [
        {name: 'TotalConfirmed', imgSrc: '../assets/icons/virus2.svg'},
        {name: 'NewDeaths', imgSrc: '../assets/icons/death.svg'},
        ]
    })
```

#### Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please test this: `{name: 'TotalConfirmed', imgSrc: require('../assets/icons/virus2.svg')}` and in your `src` just call the `imgSrc` means `:src="property.imgSrc"`

Comment: What is `require` here?

Answer (score -1):

Access `imgSrc` in the current `property`-object in the loop:

```html
<img :src="property.imgSrc">
```